# Using Gate between Mac and Windows via Bitbucket.org

Tags: windows, nlp, gate

I'm trying to collaborate with with a colleague on a Gate app. He uses a Mac, while I am on Windows. We are both on Gate 8.5.1. He has uploaded the current project to a Bitbucket.org account.

My method is to download the entire folder from - https://bitbucket.org/our username/our project name/downloads/ - save it across to my Gate folder in Program Files, and then open the GAPP file. This opens GATE, but with none of the configuration (Gazzateers, JAPE rules etc), just a standard unmodified version of GATE.

I'm not sure if the File paths which he has chosen are not mapping across to my system, or there is some other element of his set it up which is different.

Is there an easy way to drag and drop a configured Gate application from one operating system (OSX) to the another (Windows)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the gate manual on "[Saving Applications and Language Resources](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch3.html#x6-520003.9)". I think for beginners it's best to export the whole pipeline and resources in a zip file using the method [described here](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch3.html#x6-560003.9.4).

In general, you don't need the GATE installation and binaries in your bitbucket project. You only need the configuration and code, specific to your application.

Keep in mind that if you use / edit any of the GATE PRs, like ANNIE gazetteers, japes, etc., you need to make sure they're all properly exported / updated within your team and working environments. (That's why I recommend the export for cloud option, because it exports all resources and updates paths so that they're all put in a common folder).